# How do you create a sql query including multiple rows in one table as columns

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables, students and contacts tables. There can be no more than 3 contacts per student.

```
Students table:
ID, Name
123, John
456, Jane

Contacts table:
ID, CO, Name, Relation
123, C1, Jill, Mother
123, C2, Doug, Father
123, C3, Larry, Brother
456, C1, Luis, Father
456, C2, Jill, Mother
```

I want sql output to look like this:

```
ID, Name, C1, C1name, C1rel, C2, C2name, C2rel, C3, C3name, C3rel
123, John, C1, Jill, Mother, C2, Doug, Father, C3, Larry, Brother
456, Jane, C1, Luis, Father, C2, Jill, Mother
```

This is for an export to upload to a third party vendor. Thank you.

Comment: What DBMS are you using?  MySql, SQL Server, Oracle, etc.?

Comment: If youre using SQL. Look up the `PIVOT` command.

Comment: The term you are looking for is 'pivot' and there are alot of examples on stackoverflow to look at.  If you want more of an answer..pivot syntax varies alot between databases and youi'll need to answer the question from Siyual above before anyone can answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use a case statement or sub queries.

```
SELECT ID, Name,

  (SELECT CO FROM Contacts c
   WHERE s.ID = c.ID
   AND c.CO = "C1") END AS C1,

  (SELECT Name FROM Contacts c
   WHERE s.ID = c.ID
   AND c.CO = "C1") END AS C1name,

  (SELECT Relation FROM Contacts c
   WHERE s.ID = c.ID
   AND c.CO = "C1") END AS C1rel
FROM Students s
```

And so on

Comment: This is using MS-SQL. This doesn't seem to work for me. Getting Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.

Comment: Which DBMS(Database such as: MYSQL, SQL SERVER etc..) are you using so that I can give you the correct syntax for that DBMS

Comment: I think I figured it out, but I get 2 records short as soon as I combine with my Contacts table